# Thunderbird - quit when close

Tags: applications

When I close the windows of Thunderbird 38, it is because I have finished to work on my mails.
But Thunderbird is still running and can tell me when new mails are arrived.

For now, I have to click-right on Thunderbird to quit.

Is there a way to quit Thunderbird when I close the window?

I am using Mac OSX 10.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as on Macintosh closing Applications' windows ( by either clicking on the *top-left* **red button** or doing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> ) doesn't quit it.

To quit it, instead of closing all windows, you have to actively go into the menu option through ***[Application Name]* / Quit *[Application Name]*** or by doing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>